# How to iterate even for those minutes where there are no zero seconds

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file where there are a lot of time values.

| Time | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 10:00:00 | 1 |
| 10:00:00 | 2 |
| 10:00:00 | 8 |
| 10:00:01 | 5 |
| 10:01:02 | 6 |
| 10:01:02 | 3 |
| 10:01:03 | 4 |

I have a function that takes the first value of each minute and subtracts from it all the last values of each second of that minute

```
def Comulativ_delta():
    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(Ex_Csv, usecols = ['time', 'value'], parse_dates=[1]))
    df['value'] = df['value'].astype(int)
    a = df['time']
    data = df[pd.to_datetime(df.time,format= '%H:%M:%S' ).dt.second == 0].groupby('time').agg("first").reset_index()
    data["hour_and_min"] = pd.to_datetime(data.time,format= '%H:%M:%S' ).dt.strftime("%H:%M")
    res = df.groupby('time').agg("last").reset_index()
    res["hour_and_min"] = pd.to_datetime(res.time,format= '%H:%M:%S' ).dt.strftime("%H:%M")
    a = pd.DataFrame(pd.merge(res, data, on="hour_and_min").apply(lambda x: [x.value_x - x.value_y,   f"{x.time_y}-{x.time_x}"], axis=1).tolist(), columns=['value', 'time'])
    a.to_excel('Datasets\\Data\\Cumulative_delta.xlsx', )
    a.to_csv('Datasets\\CSV\\Cumulative_delta.csv', )
    print('s')
```

dt.second == 0 sets which seconds of the minute to take as the beginning

But in csv there are minutes that start for example from 10:17:02.
And in the final calculation, I get a csv with the missed minutes, which does not suit me

I tried to apply .all() and (or, and) and the for loop, but I can't account for minutes that don't start with 0 seconds

Comment: You could try using `df_time.resample(...)` to get a series with all the minutes you want, including the 'missing' ones?  See examples at: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html

Comment: What is the expected output for your example?

Comment: So that even if a minute starts at 10:17:02, he also took it into account in the csv file, and my code counts only minutes with the beginning of 10:17:00 seconds

Comment: Now the output is something like this 
4,10:16:00-10:16:59
8,10:18:00-10:18:00
11,10:18:00-10:18:01

With the omission of the value
And I expect

4,10:16:00-10:16:59
2,10:17:01-10:17:01
4,10:17:01-10:17:02
8,10:18:00-10:18:00
11,10:18:00-10:18:01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided it like this

```
def Comulativ_delta():
    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(Ex_Csv, usecols = ['Time', 'Value'], parse_dates=[0]))
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(Ex_Csv, usecols = ['Time', 'Value'], parse_dates=[0]))
    df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.floor("T", 0).dt.time
    df1['Time'] = df1['Time'].dt.floor("S", 0).dt.time
    data = df.groupby('Time').agg("first").reset_index()
    data["hour_and_min"] = pd.to_datetime(data.Time,format= '%H:%M:%S' ).dt.strftime("%H:%M")
    res = df1.groupby('Time').agg("last").reset_index()
    res["hour_and_min"] = pd.to_datetime(res.Time,format= '%H:%M:%S' ).dt.strftime("%H:%M")
    A = pd.DataFrame(pd.merge(res, data, on="hour_and_min").apply(lambda x: [x.Value_x - x.Value_y,   f"{x.Time_x}-{x.Time_y}"], axis=1).tolist(), columns=['value', 'time'])
```

In the primary csv, I set the step "T", which turned into 0 even those minutes that start with 01, and so on for a few seconds

Which ultimately saved me from missing seconds.